# How to perform subtraction between Text Field and Variable

Tags: jasper-reports

I am very new with ireport-5.6.0.

I have one text field(**Sanctioned_intake**) and one i declare variable(**ROPORT_COUNT**)**.Sanctioned_intake** is nothing but total number of Student per Department and **REPORT_COUNT** is return total no of rows which is enter into the report

For Example:

Sanctioned Intake:140 (Total Student per Department)

Actual Admitted: 10 (Actual Admission Taking)

So Difference Should Be:

Vacancy : 130(Remaining Vacancy )

now my question is how to make difference between this two

I declare One Variable

and set the following properties

variable class=java.math.BigDecimal
Calculation    Sum
Reset Type     Report
Variable Expression:   $F{sanctioned_intake}.substract($V{REPORT_COUNT})

But i got this error

```
Error filling print... Error evaluating expression :      Source text : $F{sanctioned_intake}.substract$V{REPORT_COUNT} 
        net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression :      
    Source text : $F{sanctioned_intake}.substract$V{REPORT_COUNT}  
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluateEstimated(JREvaluator.java:327)  
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
No signature of method: java.lang.String.substract() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [1] 
Possible solutions: substring(int), substring(int, int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Data Type of $V{REPORT_COUNT} is integer.

Check data types of each field and variable.

Or if datatype of $F{sanctioned_intake} == BigDecimal then change variable expression to below

$F{sanctioned_intake}.substract(new BigDecimal($V{REPORT_COUNT}))

Comment: But how can i check the fields type. ,In xml  field name and class is given. field type is not there how can i checked this?i tryed to change both class type class = "java.math.BigDecimal" and the variable which i declare to take difference also keep class type="java.math.BigDecimal" and in the variable expression i set $F{sanctioned_intake}.substract(new BigDecimal($V{REPORT_COUNT}))                                                                 now i get this error "the method substract(Big Decimal) is undefined for the type BigDecimal

Comment: you can see it from fields section

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to that `$F{sanctioned_intake}` is declared as `java.lang.String`.

```
<field name="sanctioned_intake" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

However I do not think you will achieve your excepted result changing it to `java.math.BigDecimal` since jasper report has something called [EvalutationTime](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/EvaluationTimeEnum.html), the `$V{REPORT_COUNT}` will start with 0 and reach the total report count only when all records have been displayed.

To the display the difference of 2 fields, declare them as Integer (if you can not, you need to parse them before calculating difference) and then use a text field.

example consider that $F's are `java.lang.Integer`

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="163" y="16" width="100" height="20" uuid="4196bd23-306b-44f6-8e3e-4d637facacf6"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{sanctioned_intake}.intValue()-$F{actual_admitted.intValue()}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

If one needs to be calculated use a variable, calculating (count) and resetting it as needs and then set correct evaluation time on your textField (so that the variables have time to be calculated)

example

```
<textField evaluationTime="Report">
    <reportElement x="163" y="16" width="100" height="20" uuid="4196bd23-306b-44f6-8e3e-4d637facacf6"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{sanctioned_intake}.intValue()-$V{actual_admitted}.intValue()]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Note: you are using `language="groovy"` maybe you like to use `language="java"` on your `jasperReport` tag.

Comment: i declared both sanctioned_intake text  field and  variable REPORT_COUNT as java.lang.Integer and set calculating as (count) and use language='java' am getting 0(zero) value but  what u mentioned above " then use a text field." i didn't get this where we have to add this fields i have one text field sanctioned_intake and and one variable REPORT_COUNT and one more variable to store final result

Comment: @Anwar variable REPORT_COUNT is a jasper report variable (that counts the records as it is filling the detail band)... Use a textField means that you if you are uing iReport, drag the variable into the band... then on basis of evaluationTime (see property of textfield) you will have different result es. REPORT_COUNT will be 0 if you set now, if you set page it will increment with number of records on page, if you set report it will be all the records).... This is what I'm trying to say... ok to use variables, but you must also set correct evaluationTime on the textField (time to be calculated)